# How to define property in json which is inconsistent, Android

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use `FirebaseRecyclerView` in which the property of JSON is inconsistent. I.e. it keeps on changing for each user. So I want to know if there is any way to define property which can change (n ya it would be in database.)

The situation is that property `UserID` is inconsistent as it would be different for every user

```
public class FriendsData {
  String picurl;
  String userNAME;
  String status;
  String UserID;

  Map<String, Boolean> emails = new HashMap<>();

  public FriendsData(){      
  }

  public Map<String, Boolean> getEmails() {
    return emails;
  }
  public void setEmails(Map<String, Boolean> emails) {
    this.emails = emails;
  }

  public String getPicurl() {
    return picurl;
  }
  public void setPicurl(String picurl) {
    this.picurl = picurl;
  }

  public String getUserNAME() {
    return userNAME;
  }
  public void setUserNAME(String userNAME) {
    this.userNAME = userNAME;
  }

  public String getStatus() {
    return status;
  }
  public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
  }
}
```

So how to define the Inconsistent variable in friendsData class

**Edit**
I have added a child named Friends To make it simple

```
 {
 "rootssahaj" : {
 "authGplus" : {
  "dummy_1@gmail" : {
    "friends" : {
      "sahaj9917730102" : true
    },
    "picurl" : "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jigsoar-icons/64/_thumbnails.png",
    "userNAME" : "dummy_1"
  },
  "dummy_2@gmail" : {
    "picurl" : "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jigsoar-icons/64/_thumbnails.png",
    "status" : "hey! everyone",
    "userNAME" : "Dummy Head 2",
    "friends" : {
      "sahaj9917730102" : true
    },
  },
  "dummy_3@gmail" : {
    "picurl" : "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jigsoar-icons/64/_thumbnails.png",
    "userNAME" : "dummy_3",
     "friends" : {
      "dummy_1" : true
    },
  },
  "dummy_4@gmail" : {
    "picurl" : "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jigsoar-icons/64/_thumbnails.png",
    "sahaj" : false,
    "userNAME" : "dummy_4"
    "friends" : {
      "sahaj9917730102" : true
    },
  },
  "dummy_5@gmail" : {
    "picurl" : "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jigsoar-icons/64/_thumbnails.png",
    "sahaj" : false,
    "userNAME" : "dummy_6"
  },
  "dummy_6@gmail" : {
    "picurl" : "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jigsoar-icons/64/_thumbnails.png",
    "sahaj" : true,
    "userNAME" : "dummy_6"
  },
  "dummy_7@gmail" : {
    "picurl" : "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jigsoar-icons/64/_thumbnails.png",
    "sahaj" : true,
    "userNAME" : "dummy_7"
  },
  "sahaj9917730102@gmail" : {
    "friends" : {
      "1111" : "true"
    },
    "gplusURL" : "https://plus.google.com/102360558702530736964",
    "picurl" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-MNhJsG93Tmk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGo/Y5wKvm71Hlg/photo.jpg?sz=400",
    "picurl50DP" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-MNhJsG93Tmk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGo/Y5wKvm71Hlg/photo.jpg?sz=50",
    "userEmail" : "sahaj9917730102@gmail.com",
    "userNAME" : "Sahaj Rana"
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're trying to do. Can you click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36227295/edit) link add a snippet of the JSON (as text, no screenshot) to your question?

Comment: I have added it what u were saying... Have a look

Comment: Put in the real JSON. Feel free to blur out values, but without seeing your real property names I can't help.

Comment: Thanks. But that's still not JSON. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the actual JSON makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Okie so i think now I have Added the right Json

Comment: OK. Now please clean up your question and remove the duplicated stuff. Since there are now three tries at including the JSON, the first two are not needed.

Comment: Aside from that, this now reads like you're trying to join the data of users in a list of friends. I just answered a question on that exact topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235919/how-to-use-a-firebaserecycleradapter-with-a-dynamic-reference-in-android

Comment: okie thanks i will look up to that solution