# How to retrieve data from one single userID Firebase Android

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, userid

In my firebase database, I have list of users that have different information under them. I would like to retrieve information from a single userId, which I will define in the code and I want to only get information from that user.

My data looks like;

```
UserTable
{
  "fmXWU324VHdDb8v6h7gvNjRojnu33" : {
    "-KbJtw467nl6p253HZ537" : {
      "Name" : "name1",
      "Email" : "something1@something.com",
      "userid" : "fmXWU324VHdDb8v6h7gvNjRojnu33"
    }
  },
  "pJtC45fW0MMi352UiPWnWdIS7h88" : {
    "-Kb012ls9iMnzEL723o9I" : {
      "Name" : "name2",
      "Email" : "something2@something.com",
      "userid" : "pJtC45fW0MMi352UiPWnWdIS7h88"
    },
    "-Kb0aq0q25FJq38256SrC" : {
      "Name" : "name3",
      "Email" : "something3@something.com",
      "userid" : "pJtC45fW0MMi352UiPWnWdIS7h88"
    },
    "-Kb0atopfK64F6jy124Qi1u" : {
      "Name" : "name3",
      "Email" : "something1@something.com",
      "userid" : "pJtC45fW0MMi352UiPWnWdIS7h88"
  }
}
```

and I want to, say for example read and display all data from this user `"fmXWU324VHdDb8v6h7gvNjRojnu33"`. I am not sure how I can do that. I tried this, which seems logical but it doesn't seem to work:

```
df.child("UserTable").child(user.getUid())).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
```

it gives this error:

```
Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.android.example.UserTable
```

In addition, I have tried:

```
df.child("UsersTable").child("userid").child(user.getUid()).ad‌​dChildEventListener(‌​new ChildEventListener()
```

I can seem to figure out what I am doing wrong, as what I have tried seems logical and should work. Please can someone help me out.

EDITED:

```
public ArrayList<data> get(String userID){

      df.child("UsersTable").child(userID).ad‌​dChildEventListener(‌​new ChildEventListener()  {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        fetch(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        fetch(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

return data;
```

**Update**

```
private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{

    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {
        Userdetail userdetail =ds.getValue(Userdetail.class);
        userdetails.add(userdetail );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code within child event listener. The error seems to propagate from there

Comment: Please see update

Comment: Why are you using key inside u_id?

Comment: its push Id to store entries from same user as unique. because 1 user can add multiple data under they id and I want each data to be unique and not override the previous

Comment: ohk i add the solution check it

Comment: You can read more about how to work with Firebase retrieve data in the official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Comment: @FranciscoDurdinGarcia Thanks for the link. I am having 1 issue and I have search everyone but I can't seem to find a solution. I have a recylerview to which I am loading the data from Firebase, however, recylerview does not automatically show data and I have to click on a edittext to load the data. I think this might be because the layout/recylerview is not refreshing but I have tried almost everything I could find but I can't seem to fix it. Do you know a solution?

Comment: @JoshJoe Are you calling `notifyDataSetChanged();`after set your new values? Also, why you are not using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to works with `RecyclerView` and Firebase? The API give you some support classes to implement this kind of things more easily, as `RecyclerViews` and `Lists`

Comment: @JoshJoe You can find a good example about how to use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` in the next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235919/how-to-use-a-firebaserecycleradapter-with-a-dynamic-reference-in-android

Comment: Yes, I have tried but no luck

Comment: I didn't come across FirebaseRecyclerAdapter when I started my project and I am 70% finish if I change now I will need to change 60% of the code. Which will be a nightmare :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First initialize your database like this

```
mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("your_node_name");
```

then try setting a `ValueEventListener` to your Database reference. 
Inside the `onDataChange` method you can retrieve your data like this

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    User user= dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
}
```

EDIT:

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        User user= dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I am not sure how this would work because you haven't added any listener.

Comment: Currently as my code is, I am able to retrieve data but the data is being retrieved from all users I want to only get from defined userid

Comment: Thanks for the update, could I please check how I can retirve data only from one user (for a user which I give userid for)

Comment: I was facing same situation with ChildEventListener, you can use a ValueEventListener in your database reference and change the reference to `mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("your_node_name").child("userID");`

Comment: Do you know how I can delete specific entry from firebase, given a uId and pushID?

Comment: You're welcome, just use `mDatabase.removeValue();` to remove the  child!

Comment: Also, I have my data being loaded in in recylerview from firebase. However, the recylerview does not automatically refresh and I to click an editbox to make the the appear on the app. Do you know how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

```
  DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("UsersTable").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists())
        {
            for(DataSnapshot userDetails : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d("valueName:", userDetails.child("Name").getValue());
                Log.d("valueEmail:", userDetails.child("Email").getValue());
                Log.d("valueuserid:", userDetails.child("userid").getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

use this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.android.example.UserTable

Comment: you are using fetch(dataSnapshot); method?

Comment: Yes. I have a for loop in that method doing exactly this for(DataSnapshot userDetails : dataSnapshot.getChildren()

Comment: remove the loop from your fetch(dataSnapshot);  and run.

Comment: Please see update. If i remove loop how would the data be retrieved

Answer (score 0):

Add value event listener instead of child event listener.

```
df.child("UsersTable").child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(newValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           if(dataSnapshot!=null){
             fetch(dataSnapshot);
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you know how I can delete specific entry from firebase, given a uId and pushID?

Comment: Try this `firebaseRef.child(uid).removeValue()`

Comment: To remove
         `ref.child(userid).setValue(null);`