# Firebase user details are not retrieved in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am storing user details 'firstname' and 'lastname' in UserNode. But when i want to retrieve that details then  no data is being retrieved. I tried almost all solutions on the internet but nothing solved my problem. Here is my code for retrieving data of the current user:

```
FirebaseUser userr = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (userr != null) {
        String name = userr.getDisplayName();
        Log.e("value", name);

    }
```

but it says "println needs a message"

I also tried with this but nothing happened:

```
DatabaseReference DataRef;
    DataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserNode");

    DataRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String acctname = (String)dataSnapshot.child("firstname").getValue();
            Log.e("name", acctname);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[image: Here is the structure of database]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crj7Y.png)

Please help me I am stuck with it

Comment: yes sir @Tomas wait a second i am going to edit the post

Comment: @Tomas I  have updated the code kindly check

Comment: "I am storing user details 'firstname' and 'lastname' in UserNode" - The code you shared doesn't show that. Please update your question to include the [minimum, complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link - while long, it is incredibly useful). Also update your question to include the JSON as text, instead of a link to an image. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading a collection of user with a `ValueEventListener`. As the [Firebase documentation for reading lists with a value event](Listen for value events) explains:

> While using a `ChildEventListener` is the recommended way to read lists of data, there are situations where attaching a `ValueEventListener` to a list reference is useful.
>
> Attaching a `ValueEventListener` to a list of data will return the entire list of data as a single `DataSnapshot`, which you can then loop over to access individual children.
>
> Even when there is only a single [child node], the snapshot is still a list; it just contains a single item. To access the item, you need to loop over the result.

So in your code:

```
DatabaseReference DataRef;
DataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserNode");

DataRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String acctname = (String)childSnapshot.child("firstname").getValue();
            Log.i("name", acctname);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Thankyou for answeing, and sorry for late response, Sir getChildren() is giving error and showing red line and it says "non-static method getChildren cannot be referenced from a static context.
What to do in this case?

Comment: Oops... that was a typo: `DataSnapshot.getChildren()` -> `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`. Fixed.

Comment: Still the same issue, :( println needs a message

Comment: There was another type. Sorry about that, sometimes the copy/paste/modify goes awry. But I'm not sure what you mean about println, since there is no such call in my aswer.

Comment: I have been trying to solve the issue from 3 days but no one gives me correct answer. But you are genious. Thankyou it works thanks a lot for help :)
Just one last thing, it shows all the firstnames of the UserNode data. How to show only current user firstname who is logged in

Answer (score 0):

Please, read [how to retrieve data from firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data). I think you have a problem because you don't have **Class Model**.

Your steps:

1. Create model UserModel with firstname and lastname field
2. Use listener (example from docs):

   ```
   // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
   ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
           System.out.println(post);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
       }
   });
   ```
3. See other answers: [How to retrieve data from one single userID Firebase Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851973/how-to-retrieve-data-from-one-single-userid-firebase-android) and [retrieving data from firebase android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192113/retrieving-data-from-firebase-android)

Comment: a Java class to represent the data is recommended, but not necessary. In Arslan's code `dataSnapshot.child("firstname").getValue()` will get the `firstname` property of the snapshot and then return the value as its native underlying type (likely a `String` given the property name).

Answer (score 0):

Using **`FirebaseUser`**:

`FirebaseUser` implements `UserInfo` and in `UserInfo`'s [`getDisplayName()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo.html#getDisplayName()) documentation says

> Returns the user's display name, **if available**.

So, it is possible that [`FirebaseUser.getDisplayName()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getDisplayName()) return `null` when display name is not set. In that case [`Log.e()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#e(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) receives `null` as message and therefore prints **println needs a message**

**Using your own structure:**

Instead of using type conversion use [`getValue(Class<T>)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) like so:

```
String acctname = dataSnapshot.child("firstname").getValue(String.class);
```

Comment: Do you mean `println needs a message`

Comment: Try System.out.println() instead of Log.e() and comment the output

Comment: Should i need to create some class as the developer said in the solution above this solution. Please check that

Comment: The error `println needs a message` occurs when `name` in `String name = userr.getDisplayName();` is null. Your user might be missing a display name.

Comment: My firstname and lastname is not the user displayname?

Comment: Your firstname and lastname is not display name from `FirebaseUser`

Comment: Can you please guide me with the Model class for firstname and lastname as I am very new to android and firebase. It would be appreicated

Comment: @ArslanAli, i write link on docs in my quetion. Please, see here.