# Getting 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference' even when the reference is not null

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm using `FirebaseUI` in my app and `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to be more specific.

I'm fetching data from my `FirebaseDatabase` reference using the method given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36236657/6144372).

Here's my code:

```
private void attachRecyclerViewAdapter() {
        Query lastFifty = mDatabase.child(rID).limitToFirst(50);
        mRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AModelClass, AModelClass.ViewHolder>(
                AModelClass.class, R.layout.a_player_layout, APlayersModelClass.ViewHolder.class, lastFifty) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(AModelClass.ViewHolder viewHolder, AsModelClass model, int position) {

                String key = this.getRef(position).getKey();
                aReference.child(requestID).child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

                            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                            pA = map.get("pName");
                            uA = map.get("pUrl"); 
                            // error on line below
                            String cLatS = map.get("cLat").trim();
                            currentLtAU = Double.parseDouble(cLatS);
                            String cLngS = map.get("cLng").trim();
                            currentLnAU = Double.parseDouble(cLngS);

                            viewHolder.setPName(pA);
                            viewHolder.setPUrl(uA);
                            viewHolder.setCurrentLatAU(String.valueOf(currentLtAU));
                            viewHolder.setCurrentLngAU(String.valueOf(currentLnAU));

                        } else {
                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "Some error occurred. Please retry!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            snackbar.show();
                            onBackPressed();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        };

        aList.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);
    }
```

Here's how database structure looks like:

```
-app
  -requestID
    -uniqueKey1
      -key: value
      -key: value
      -cLat: value
    -uniqueKey2
      -key: value
      -key: value
      -cLat: value
```

As you can see in the database structure above, reference has 2 `keys` and all the data is getting fetched and shown in the `RecyclerView` but as soon as one key is removed from the reference, the app crashes giving this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference` on the line specified above.

The reference has one `key` still and all the same fields which I'm fetching are in this one key too. Then **why am I** getting this error?

Comment: Why are you using a Hashmap and not `AModelClass`?

Comment: @cricket_007 how can I use `AModelClass`? Please let me know.

Comment: I don't know what your model class looks like, but you're using Firebase-ui to specify a model class for your adapter, but you never use it... `dataSnapshot.getValue` takes a class parameter, OR, you can use that `AsModelClass model` parameter, I think

Comment: @cricket_007 hey hey... can you write a small example? I'm a bit confused here. Please?

Comment: Like I said, look at the parameters of `populateViewHolder`. You have a model there. Why not use it?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I got your point.. haven't done it before that's why asking for an example. Please...

Comment: I don't know what you want to see... `model.getcLat()`??

Comment: @cricket_007 I think I got the problem.. which is that as soon as I'm removing the key and the value inside it, it is not getting fully removed and the code under `populateViewHolder` is getting called with the partially removed value and thus this error. 

So, how can I remove it completely before the code under `populateViewHolder` gets called? and it should get called only with the remaining `key`(s).

Comment: @cricket_007 here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41925181/6144372 I asked a new question based on the problem I figured out. Please take a look.

Comment: I'm not that great with firebase api, but I do think you shouldn't put an asynchronous `new ValueEventListener` inside of the method that only exists to populate the view holder with the provided `model` parameter, which is a synchronous method.

Comment: @cricket_007 I wasn't doing this before but this was the only way as using the `ValueEventListener` before the `populateViewHolder()` method emerged this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41910271/6144372 then I did some research and find out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36236657/6144372 which I'm following now.

Answer (score 1):

If this causes the error:

```
Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
String cLatS = map.get("cLat").trim();
```

The reason is most likely, that `dataSnapshot` has no child `cLat`.

You should check with `.hasChild("cLat")` - see [DataSnapshot](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/DataSnapshot.html#getValue--)

... or prevent the attempted `.trim(null)` alike:

```
if(map.get("cLat") != null) {
    String cLatS = map.get("cLat").trim();
    currentLtAU = Double.parseDouble(cLatS);
}
```

While for this kind of application, you might want to check out Firebase [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire).

Comment: please see updated question.. I added the database structure.

Comment: I figured out what is causing this error and have posted a new question based on that problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41925181/6144372 Please help with it. Thanks!

Comment: @HammadNasir nevertheless I've answered this question; so this answer should be accepted.