# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter's populateViewHolder() getting called before a key having certain values gets fully removed thus giving nullpointerexception

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using `FirebaseUI`'s `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` in my app to fetch some data from a FirebaseDatabase reference and show it in a `RecyclerView`. I'm completing this task successfully.

Here's my code:

```
private void attachRecyclerViewAdapter() {
        Query lastFifty = mDatabase.child(rID).limitToFirst(50);
        mRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AModelClass, AModelClass.ViewHolder>(
                AModelClass.class, R.layout.a_player_layout, APlayersModelClass.ViewHolder.class, lastFifty) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(AModelClass.ViewHolder viewHolder, AsModelClass model, int position) {

                String key = this.getRef(position).getKey();
                aReference.child(requestID).child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

                            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                            pA = map.get("pName");
                            uA = map.get("pUrl"); 
                            // error on line below
                            String cLatS = map.get("cLat").trim();
                            currentLtAU = Double.parseDouble(cLatS);
                            String cLngS = map.get("cLng").trim();
                            currentLnAU = Double.parseDouble(cLngS);

                            viewHolder.setPName(pA);
                            viewHolder.setPUrl(uA);
                            viewHolder.setCurrentLatAU(String.valueOf(currentLtAU));
                            viewHolder.setCurrentLngAU(String.valueOf(currentLnAU));

                        } else {
                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "Some error occurred. Please retry!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            snackbar.show();
                            onBackPressed();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        };

        aList.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);
    }
```

Here's database structure's representation:

```
-app
  -requestID
    -uniqueKey1
      -key: value
      -key: value
      -cLat: value
    -uniqueKey2
      -key: value
      -key: value
      -cLat: value
```

**The problem is** that as soon as I remove `uniqueKey1` from the database, the code inside the `populateViewHolder()` method is called and the data under `uniqueKey1` don't gets removed completely and thus `aReference.child(requestID).child(key)` takes the `uniqueKey1` again but this time some of the data, specifically `cLat` is removed from here and thus the app crashes giving `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference` error on the line specified in the code.

**What I want** to know is how can I let the the code inside `populateViewHolder()` called only when the `uniqueKey1` along with the data under it is completely removed and then the `aReference.child(requestID).child(key)` takes only `uniqueKey2` (remaining key(s)) as parameter to load data again and show in recyclerview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I figured out a way.

Just placed some conditions in the code.

Here's the updated code:

```
    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

         if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("pName") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("pUrl") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("cLat") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("cLng")) {

                 Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                 pA = map.get("pName");
                 uA = map.get("pUrl");
                 String cLatS = map.get("cLat").trim();
                 currentLtAU = Double.parseDouble(cLatS);
                 String cLngS = map.get("cLng").trim();
                 currentLnAU = Double.parseDouble(cLngS);

                 viewHolder.setPName(pA);
                 viewHolder.setPUrl(uA);
                 viewHolder.setCurrentLatAU(String.valueOf(currentLtAU));
                 viewHolder.setCurrentLngAU(String.valueOf(currentLnAU));

          }
     }
```

and now everything works perfectly fine!