# Firebase get post of the following user only

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to show the post of the user someone id following.
I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to get posts.

my Database id structure as below is json

```
"Allposts" : {

"-LnDkoPgr0fPAUSnackF" : {
  "author" : "jack",
  "postimage" : "posturl",
  "profile" : "profileurl",
  "uid" : "8WZ6jPIvVuNUEjR1G1ewEPpr2Ln2"
},
"-Lnll3vNF8wABv899SoQ" : {
  "author" : "merry",
  "postimage" : "posturl",
  "profile" : "profileurl",
  "uid" : "KOag2Br7MOaJqJNSFbcTD3ljEnh2"
}

"Users" : {
    "8WZ6jPIvVuNUEjR1G1ewEPpr2Ln2" : {
      "following" : {
        "KOag2Br7MOaJqJNSFbcTD3ljEnh2" : true
      },
      "name" : "username",
      "posts" : {
        "-KnDkoPdke4p4Ns8NUkR" : true
      },

      "profilepic" : "profileurl",
      "userName" : "username"
    },
    "KOag2Br7MOaJqJNSFbcTD3ljEnh2" : {

      "following" : {
        "8WZ6jPIvVuNUEjR1G1ewEPpr2Ln2" : true,
        "KOag2Br7MOaJqJNSFbcTD3ljEnh2" : true
      },
      "name" : "name",
      "posts" : {
        "-KnDl3vFUlSxyRm0z547" : true
      },
      "profilepic" : "profileurl",
      "userName" : "username"
    }
  },

"UsersPost" : {
    "8WZ6jPIvVuNUEjR1G1ewEPpr2Ln2" : {
      "-KnDkoPdke4p4Ns8NUkR" : {
        "author" : "jack",
        "full_url" : "posturl",
        "profile" : "profileurl",
        "uid" : "8WZ6jPIvVuNUEjR1G1ewEPpr2Ln2"
      }
    },
    "KOag2Br7MOaJqJNSFbcTD3ljEnh2" : {
      "-KnDl3vFUlSxyRm0z547" : {
        "author" : "marry",
        "full_url" : "posturl",
        "profile" : profileurl",
        "uid" : "KOag2Br7MOaJqJNSFbcTD3ljEnh2"
      }
    }
  },
```

},

I am using following method to get following posts

```
mFollowing = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUser).child("following");
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UsersPost");

protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mFollowing.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot following : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                   DatabaseReference ref =  mDatabase.child(following.getKey());
                    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(Post.class,
                            R.layout.post_item,PostViewHolder.class,ref) {
                        @Override
                        protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, Post model, int position) {
                            viewHolder.bindToPost(model);
                        }
                    };
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

But it shows the post of the last user only:

```
Users {
    following {
        userid (1)
        userid (2)
        userid (3)
    }
}
```

only post of uid 3 is shown post of uid 1 & 2 are not shown

what could be done to show post of all user under following node ?

Comment: Anybody please give answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get `mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);` out from the `for loop` and place it after the for loop ends.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did it but still no working do you have any other idea to get only post of user following?

Comment: No answer by any developer?

Comment: This is an question which do not have any answers by any expert here

Comment: Try to get this line `DatabaseReference ref =  mDatabase.child(following.getKey());` out too from the for loop.

Comment: How can we do that? It will not be accessable outside loop I think

Comment: That's the point, to be outside the loop. Inside you are creating a new instance every time you loop.

Comment: Any other way to get post's? You can suggest

Comment: Try to read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235919/how-to-use-a-firebaserecycleradapter-with-a-dynamic-reference-in-android)

Comment: @ Alex Mamo , Thanks bro it worked.I was looking for this only .Thank you so much

Comment: Happy to hear that. So, if you think my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `datasnapshot`per se. This should work fine, since you are using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`:

```
mFollowing = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUser).child("following");
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UsersPost");

protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();    

DatabaseReference ref =  mDatabase.child(following.getKey());
                    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(Post.class,
                            R.layout.post_item,PostViewHolder.class,ref) {
                        @Override
                        protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, Post model, int position) {
                            viewHolder.bindToPost(model);
                        }
                    };
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                }

  }

}
```